# Generate timed transactional deposit wallets

Tags: wallets, qrcode

I am looking at developing a service that can take a payment in Eth and return a erc-20 token to their desired address.

I want to generate a new address per transactional user. What would be the best way to develop a wallet per transaction?

A good example is [www.latoken.com](http://www.latoken.com)

*** UPDATED ***
I have found a solution using *eth-hd-wallet* package in node. The following example creates 1 million wallets from a generated mnemonic code. Documentation can be found here: [eth-hd-wallet](https://github.com/meth-browser/eth-hd-wallet)

```
const { generateMnemonic, EthHdWallet } = require('eth-hd-wallet');

const phrase = generateMnemonic();

const wallet = EthHdWallet.fromMnemonic(phrase);

console.log(phrase);

console.log( wallet.generateAddresses(1000000));
```

To display the QR code, I can utilise Google's api to generate the QR per wallet. Link to site is here: [Google QR Code](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=0x8CCF9C4a7674D5784831b5E1237d9eC9Dddf9d7F&choe=UTF-8)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using eth-hd-wallet package in node. The following example creates 1 million wallets from a generated mnemonic code. Documentation can be found here: eth-hd-wallet

const { generateMnemonic, EthHdWallet } = require('eth-hd-wallet');

const phrase = generateMnemonic();

const wallet = EthHdWallet.fromMnemonic(phrase);

console.log(phrase);

console.log( wallet.generateAddresses(1000000));
To display the QR code, I can utilise Google's api to generate the QR per wallet. Link to site is here: Google QR Code

Thanks